# limit of p norm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $p_n=1+1/n$. Suppose that $\{s_{p_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a subset of $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ and there exists a positive constant $C$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\|s_{p_n}\|_{p_n}\leq C$. The question is whether $\{s_{p_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ or not.

---

My attempt: For $s\in\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$, let us use $s^n$ to denote the truncation of $s$ by keeping the first $n$ terms and making others to be $0$. Now with holder's inequality, we have
$$
\|s_{p_n}^n\|_1\leq n^{1-\frac{1}{p_n}}\|s_{p_n}^n\|_{p_n}=n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\|s_{p_n}^n\|_{p_n}\leq n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\|s_{p_n}\|_{p_n} \leq n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\cdot C.
$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}=1$, we can conclude that the sequence $\{\|s_{p_n}^n\|_1\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded. Recall that our goal is to prove $\{\|s_{p_n}\|_1\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded. I think there is still a gap.

Comment: The conclusion is false as the norms on $\ell^1$ and $\ell^p$ are inequivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $p_n$ there is a sequence $s_{p_n}$ with finitely many nonzero terms such that $$\|s_{p_n}\|_{p_n}\le 1,\quad \|s_{p_n}\|_{1}\to \infty$$
Indeed let
$$s_{p_n}(k)=\begin{cases} n^{-n/p_n} & k\le n^{n}\\
0 & k>n^{n}
\end{cases} $$
Then
$$\|s_{p_n}\|_{p_n}=n^{-n}n^n= 1,\quad\|s_{p_n}\|_1= n^{-n/p_n}\cdot n^n=n^{n/(n+1)}$$

Comment: A misprint. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. May I know how to construct such $s_{p_n}$ or how to guarantee the existence of such $s_{p_n}$?

Comment: It is more convenient to get $\|s_{p_n}\|_{p_n}=1$ and $\|s_{p_n}\|_1\to \infty.$